# Find a path/subpaths in a tree such that sum of weights is less than given integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree

Given a tree with n Nodes (numbered from 1 to n) and n-1 edges. Each edge has two integers, a weight and a gain, associated to it. You are also given a number K. You can start with any node , and you have to make trades. In each trade you lose the amount equal to edge's weight and earn a profit equal to the gain value of the edge. You have to maximize the profit such that the total lost amount <=K

Here's a link to the original question. The corresponding contest is now over.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/gs-quantify-2017/challenges/profit-maximization

What I did:

I built a recursive approach by considering every node as the starting node of the path and then recursively calculating the maximum profit by considering each of the subsequent nodes abiding by the constraints.

But as is evident that this has very high Time Complexity.

Is there a more elegant and time efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion:

1. Choose a node near the centre of the graph (e.g. by repeatedly trimming all leaf nodes and picking the last node deleted)
2. Work out the best profit if the solution uses that node (not necessarily as the start node - it may just be in the middle as well)
3. Work out the best profit if the solution uses each subtree in turn (i.e. does not use the chosen node)

To work out the profit for a solution using a particular node x you could use a DFS to compute the total weight and profit to reach each node.

Then for each child subtree of x:

1. Construct a sorted map from weight to profit (this map should be sorted by increasing weight)
2. Remove any entries where the profit is less than an earlier profit (no point keeping routes that weigh more but give less profit)

You can then merge these subtrees to find the maximum profit from any route that includes x:

1. Start with the sorted map for child 1
2. Iterate forwards through the map for child 1, and backwards through the map for child 2 to find the highest profit from a route starting in child 1 and ending in child 2.
3. Merge the maps for child 1 and child 2, then repeat for child 3,4,5...

Note that step 2 and step 3 are both linear in the number of entries being merged.

If there is a high branching factor, then this merging step may become too slow, in which case you could improve the efficiency by always merging the two smallest subtrees instead of just merging in order.  A Heap data structure could be used to efficiently tell you which the two smallest are.

There may well be a much simpler solution, Hackerrank normally posts editorials after a little while so it would be worth rechecking your question link in the future.